# Gemstones; seven clues

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

There are seven clues, with each clue pertaining to a specific gemstone. The first letter for each gemstone (in order) when aligned spells out another specific gemstone. So, a 7 letter gemstone. Answer with each gemstone per hint. Good luck.

Seven clues before you,
One answer you will find,
Only one solution
To which all seven bind.
If you seek a love eternal,
One must merely nock,
If you desire romance,
Name El Toro's favorite rock.
The namesake for the season
Had cupid carved into this ring,
Just click your heels together,
Your home makes your heart sing.
The favorite gem of Gaia's twin
Is filled with beauty most devine,
The next a great alternative
To ask, "Would you be mine?"
The final gem has several faces,
Many places you can sift
To find a stone to call your own,
Twice an anniversary gift.
Now put these rocks together
Into one amazing piece
Fit for queens in London dreams
A treasure to say the least!

Comment: Should "nock" be "knock"? And should "devine" be "divine"? (They _look_ like typos. But there actually _is_ a word "nock", though it doesn't seem very likely to be what's meant here, and sometimes puzzles have deliberate mistakes in them.)

Comment: Can you take a close look at the use of periods and commas?

Answer (score 3):

#### **Answer**

A plausible solution could be

> **DRAVITE**

#### **Explanation**

Disclaimer: each site gives a different and distorted significance to each stone. The above solution is composed of references from different sites to come up with a seven-letter gem as the answer. With that said, the following explains the gems inferred from each clue. The lines have been condensed to for readability.

*If you seek a love eternal, one must merely nock,*

> **D**iamond is widely known as the gem of [eternal love](https://shahlakarimi.com/pages/the-meaning-behind-stones)

*If you desire romance, name El Toro's favorite rock.*

> **R**uby, also a [gem of love](http://www.gongoff.com/symbology/the-ruby-symbolism-of-the-stone), was used to build the [*El Toro* sculpture](https://blog.henngems.de/2019/07/03/ruby-el-toro/)

*The namesake for the season had cupid carved into this ring,*

> **A**mber, is also associated with [love and marriage](https://nammu.com/eng/amber-gemstone-meaning/) (since Cupid is associated with love and affection)

*Just click your heels together, your home makes your heart sing.*

> **V**ariscite, said to bring joyous feelings of [peace and harmony to your heart](https://www.healing-crystals-for-you.com/variscite.html)

*The favorite gem of Gaia's twin; is filled with beauty most divine,*

> **I**mperial Jade, said to be one of the most valuable gems. It is also said to [carry the energy of the Earth and relate to Divine abundance](https://beadage.net/gemstones/jade/). Gaia in here can relate to Earth. However, Corallium medea, a species of [Precious/red coral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precious_coral), relates to Gaia's so-called twin Medea

*The next a great alternative to ask, "Would you be mine?"*

> **T**opaz, also a symbol of [love and affection](https://www.jewelsforme.com/topaz-meaning), said to speak the truth from your heart.

*The final gem has several faces; many places you can sift

To find a stone to call your own, twice an anniversary gift.*

> **E**merald, usually multi-faceted, refers to both [20th and 35th anniversaries](http://www.jewelrywise.com/gifts-occasions/article/a-guide-to-anniversary-gemstones-jewelry).

*Now put these rocks together into one amazing piece

Fit for queens in London dreams; A treasure to say the least!*

> **Dravite**, a variety of Tourmaline, could it be used in making [royal jewellery](https://www.royaldiadem.com/2013/05/brown-tourmaline/)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "click your heels together..." refers to rot13(Qbebgul'f ehol fyvccref va gur Jvmneq bs Bm)